# Mirror the change in position of an integer vector in a string vector in Quick Sort

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I have a vector of integers that relate to a vector of strings. I would like the integers to be related to the strings even after sorting. For that, I need to mirror the quick sort position switching operations. How to proceed?

The vector v before sorting is:
`54  93  55  49  60  30  27  72  40  14  21  33  76  26   7  63  50  31  17  92  11  36  52  83  22`

And the vector vP is:
`ARRUELA ABRACADEIRA PINO PORCA RELE DISJUNTOR FUSIVEL MOUSE LAMPADA TECLA CAIXA TAMPA INTERRUPTOR SOQUETE BASE LAMINA PLACA TUBO LATERAL VIDEO PLUG CABO SUPORTE BOTAO PARAFUSO`

The body of the algorithm function:

```
void quickSort(int *v, int esq, int dir){
    if (esq < dir){
        int j = separate(v, esq, dir);
        quickSort(v, esq, j - 1);
        quickSort(v, j + 1, dir);
    }
}

int separate(int *v, int esq, int dir){
    int iPivo = v[esq];
    int i = esq + 1;
    int j = dir;
    while (i <= j){
        if (v[i] <= iPivo)
            i++;
        else if (v[j] > iPivo)
            j--;
        else if (i <= j){
            change(v,i,j);
        }
    }
    change(v,esq,j);
    return j;
}

void change(int *v, int i, int j){
    int iAux;
    iAux = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = iAux;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to mirror *every* intermediate operation of quick-sort, or just the final result?

Comment: Just the final result.

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>`?  Then you can sort that by the `int` part of the pair and the string will follow along "for free".

Comment: If you use `std::sort`, this becomes rather trivial.